# Ionic Angular Mobile App showing error while fetching and displaying json-array data from a file within the project ---

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app, angular12

This is a Ionic w/ Angular mobile app. related problem, using the Ionic Framework and Angular TS as backend. Am completely new to ionic app development.

I have this stackblitz created to simulate my need --->  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6h9vwa

Objective is to bind and display category data from cat_data.json file[that will be found in the assets/data/ folder] on the categories tab page.
The error I have currently which you can see in the console there -> ***ERROR
Error: this.catData.loadCategories is not a function***

This line of code is in the backend .ts file of the category-list.html page.
Like so:

```
ionViewDidEnter()
  {
    return this.catData.loadCategories();
  }
```

Most of most of the code associated with the problem I have tried to arrange to best of my ability.
I can't get to fetch and display the data though, even after trying a multiple no. of perms. and combns.
I need to get this working. Show it in some form at least, preferably within a ion-grid and ion-row, ion-col arrangement. Hope you understand. If this is done, I can at least use this in a proper implementation.

I guess you can fork it and work/modify it or edit the original blitz itself. Feel free.

Want this working.

Answer (score 1):

In the app.module.ts remove the {provide: CategoryData, useClass: HttpClient}

and replace with

```
providers: [
     { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
     CategoryData
         ]
```

It removes the error you have.

Don't forget to subscribe to observable  and in the subscription you can normally extract data on categories.ts

```
ionViewDidEnter()
  {
    this.catData.loadCategories().subscribe(p => {
  console.log(p)
});
```

}

For the moment you get [].

On Stackblitz it's not possible to extract (or not that easy) .json file, but on your IDE it's doable. Check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55580172/16027883

On your service add :

```
  getJsonData(filePath: string){
return this.http.get(filePath);
}
```

and use it in your .ts

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
this.catData.getJsonData('./assets/cat_data.json').subscribe(resData => {
  this.data = resData;
  console.log(this.data);

     })


}
```

In the console you can see : {categories: Array(3)} with all the element. You'll need to extract that to show it in your html.

Final update :

in your page .ts

```
data: any;
dataShow = [];

  ionViewDidEnter(){
this.catData.getJsonData('./assets/cat_data.json').subscribe(resData => {
  this.data = resData;
  this.dataShow = this.data.categories
  

     })


}
```

in your html :

```
<ion-content >
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size-sm="8" offset-sm="2">
    <ion-card *ngFor="let data of dataShow">
      <ion-card-title>{{data.c_id}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{data.c_name}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-content>
        {{data.c_description}}
      </ion-card-content>
      
      
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: no, I don't use a external URL. The file is within my project structure only. A json file called cat_data.json .... and the data is in there only, as you can see in my stackblitz.    @uKioops    yes, as it is turning out atmo, the thing is not easy 
Can you tell me what do I do in such a case ..... cuz data is not coming from an external URL;    it's a headache....         any alternate idea or arrangement that would make this easier.... thanks for the expansion on the code block for data coming external URL case-scenario,

Comment: I edited my answer with some new things to try

Comment: ok it's working here. With the last update

Comment: hi @uKioops, let me have read the whole thing and go through it well, I'll revert back,

Comment: hi @uKioops, 
just asking, did you create a new separate stackblitz or edited on mine only,

Comment: I did it on my computer. On stackblitz importing data from a local json file is doable but with some tricks (that are not necessary when you code on your IDE). So you got http error because of stackblitz and not because the code is wrong. Is it working for you ?

Comment: hi @uKioops,            I now have this one -->  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ufpq76

the data you see there comes from object array declared in the .ts file itself; now wrestling with the portion on getting it from the cat_data.json. As of now, there's one error, if you inspect the console, ...     in the stackblitz --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ufpq76

i tried to log in the console and see what's coming inside ngOnInit. there's error there, ...

Comment: As I told you, this http error is not coming from the code being wrong, but because stackblitz doesn't authorized this kind of data (json) manipulation. The same code or the code I gave you will work if you try it on local on your computer.

Comment: hi, @uKioops, okay, let me try it with the code modification on VS IDE,
will update you on this,